# SQL Statement will not execute in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, syntax, jet

Hey Guys, here is my code for this, the only help i get from VS is that the INSERT INTO statement syntax is incorrect?

I have gone through all of the code and just cannot see where i have gone wrong, can someone gimme a hand please?

```
        public void New(string ApplicationStartupPath, string FileName, string Department, string Month, string Year)
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO PodcastsDir (FileName, Department, Month, Year) VALUES (@FileName, @Department, @Month, @Year)";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + ApplicationStartupPath.ToString() + ""))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", OleDbType.VarChar);

            conn.Open();

            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = FileName;
            cmd.Parameters[1].Value = Department;
            cmd.Parameters[2].Value = Month;
            cmd.Parameters[3].Value = Year;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

Thanks Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Access aren't the parameters actually place holders rather than named parameters.

Change your SQL string to use ? as a placeholder rather than a named parameter and ensure you add the parameters in the same sequence as the ? appear in the SQL string.

Comment: Then again, it might be the reserved word thing :)

Comment: Thanks dude this worked, tried the brackets but it wasnt too suree, i just changed the month and year name an then used the ? and it worked, thanks guys :)

Comment: He's not using Access at all -- he's only using Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using Access - aren't Month and Year reserved words? Try enclosing them in square brackets (is this the correct delimiter for Access?) and trying again.

Comment: He is not using Access -- he's programming in C#, and thus using only Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Access doesn't support named parameters. You should use "?" in your query to specify parameters:

```
    string sql = "INSERT INTO PodcastsDir (FileName, Department, [Month], [Year]) VALUES (?, ?,?,?)";
```

You should also put **Year** and **Month** in square brackets.

The rest of your code can be left unchanged.

Comment: Access is not involved here, as the programming environment is C#. Only Jet/ACE is involved.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this, parameters are fine in Jet ie Access

```
"INSERT INTO PodcastsDir ([FileName], [Department], [Month], [Year]) VALUES (@FileName, @Department, @Month, @Year)";
```